# Issue with Web Page Loading Timeout after iOS 17.0 Update

Tags: javascript, ajax, webview, mobile-safari

After the recent iOS update to version 17.0. Since the update, users accessing our web page via Chrome and Safari browsers on iOS 17.0 and later are experiencing loading timeouts.

**Problem Details:
**
**Issue**: Failed to load resource due to request timeout.
Affected Browsers: Chrome and Safari on iOS 17.0 and later.
Working Versions: The web page functions correctly on iOS versions 16.1 to 16.4.
Web Page Content: The web page includes JavaScript and Ajax calls.
Steps to Reproduce:

Access the web page using Chrome or Safari browser on iOS 17.0 or later.
Observe the loading timeout error.
Additional Information:

The issue seems to be related to a change in the way iOS 17.0 handles JavaScript and Ajax calls.
We have tested the web page on multiple devices running iOS 17.0 and encountered the same problem consistently.
No changes were made to the web page's codebase prior to the iOS update.

Tried with async: true but not able to see any positive results